# Does MySQLWorkbench include MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

My aim is to create some simple tables in MySQL via a GUI similar to SQL Server Management Studio. In order to do this I found and installed MySQL Workbench.

I am following this tutorial:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-admin.html

but on step 5 I get an error message saying cannot connect to MySQL server.

Am I supposed to have something else installed before I can use MySQL Workbench? I have assumed Workbench includes everything I need....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to install MySQL yourself. You can download it individually or using a tool like [WAMPserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) which makes the process of installing and configuring ridiculously easy.

Comment: Is installing MySQL without this terribly difficult? I only want to create a few tables- nothing major. I looked at that link and it looked like it would be installing much more than I need?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a server. SO you can goto start->mysql folder->mysql Installer.
After that a Mysql Installer form will open. Click on ADD. You will see a list of
products. Select Server(x86 or x64) based on your machine and follow instructions
provided.Once you have downloaded, set admin password. Now you can create your instance in workbench. If server is not running, run services.msc and start MySQL
service.